# Convert letter to number in JavaScript and calculator

Tags: javascript

```
  var letter = document.getElementById("in_text").value;
```

Get value From input box

how to Convert input letter to number
e.g A=1 B=2 C=3 ....and how to calculate =

e.g:

input: `demo`
output: `37(4 + 5 + 13 + 15)`

Comment: You can use Object/Array to store mapping or you can even use the ASCII value of the alphabets.

Comment: I would suggest you to use math.js read the idea of scope in http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html

Comment: I don't see why to do that. If you need to have exact numbers based on real position of letter in alphabet, you need simple array that will say that A = 1, B = 2 etc. (in alphabet of my language there would be else numbers). Else you may use ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

This function accepts both upper and lowercase letters, and throws out everything that is not a Basic Latin Letter (A-Z, a-z):

```
var letterSum = s =>
  s.toLowerCase().
  split('').
  map(s => s.charCodeAt(0)-0x60).
  filter(c => 1 <= c && c <= 26).
  reduce((x,y) => x+y, 0);
```

If you then try

```
alert(letterSum("demo"));
```

you will see it alert 37.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ss45w4d/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `charCodeAt` method to determine a numeric value to each character (based on its Unicode value).

For example:

```
var str = document.getElementById("in_text").value,
    numVal = 0,
    chars = str.split('');

for (var c in chars)
    numVal += (chars[c].toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) - 64);
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLb2tphe/)

Comment: @guest271314, Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculateStringValue(string) {
    var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string = string.toLowerCase();
    var value = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        value += alphabet.indexOf(string[i]) + 1;
    }

    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `String.prototype.split()`, `index` property of `String.prototype.match()`, `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/[^a-z]/ig` to replace characters that are not a-z case insensitive, `RegExp()` to match input with `i` flag, `for` loop

```js
var a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var input = document.querySelector("input");
input.oninput = input.onclick = function(e) {
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z]/ig, "");
      var res = 0;
      var n = this.value.split("");
      for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        res += a.match(new RegExp(n[i], "i")).index + 1
      }
      this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = res      
    }

input.click()
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="in_text" value="demo" title="Input letters a-z, A-Z" />
  <output>
  </output>
</form>
```